# symfony3 when I persist a new article, the user_id foreign key stay null in my article table

Tags: symfony, foreign-keys, entity, relationship, fosuserbundle

I explain my situation :

I have two entities, one is called "User" handle by fosuserBundle and another called "Article". I'll wish when I create a new Article the foreign key "fosUserId" be persisted too.

Here is my User entity :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use ArticleBundle\Entity\Article;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ArticleBundle\Entity\Article", mappedBy="fosUserId")
     */
    private $articles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->articles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set $articles
     *
     *@Param array $articles
     *
     * Return User
     */
    public function setArticles($articles)
    {
        $this->articles = $articles;
    }

    /**
     * Get articles
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getArticles()
    {
        return array('articles' => $this->articles);
    }

    /**
     * Add article
     *
     * @param \ArticleBundle\Entity\Article $article
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addArticle(\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article $article)
    {
        $this->articles[] = $article;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove article
     *
     * @param \ArticleBundle\Entity\Article $article
     */
    public function removeArticle(\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article $article)
    {
        $this->articles->removeElement($article);
    }
}
```

Here is my Article entity :

```
<?php

namespace ArticleBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ArticleBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="articles", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fosUserId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $fosUserId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="brand", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $brand;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="model", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $model;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="boolean")
     */
    private $gender;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer")
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="integer")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="imageFile", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="added", type="datetime")
     */
    private $added;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deleted;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sold", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $sold;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fosUserId
     *
     * Return integer
     */
    public function setFosUserId($fosUserId)
    {
        $this->fosUserId = $fosUserId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fosUserId
     *
     * Return Article
     */
    public function getFosUserId()
    {
        return $this->fosUserId;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param string $category
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set brand
     *
     * @param string $brand
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setBrand($brand)
    {
        $this->brand = $brand;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get brand
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBrand()
    {
        return $this->brand;
    }

    /**
     * Set model
     *
     * @param string $model
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setModel($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get model
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->model;
    }

    /**
     * Set gender
     *
     * @param boolean $gender
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setGender($gender)
    {
        $this->gender = $gender;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get gender
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getGender()
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param integer $price
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set imageFile
     *
     * @param string $imageFile
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setImageFile($imageFile)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imageFile
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    /**
     * Set added
     *
     * @param \DateTime $added
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setAdded($added)
    {
        $this->added = $added;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get added
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getAdded()
    {
        return $this->added;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * Set deleted
     *
     * @param \DateTime $deleted
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setDeleted($deleted)
    {
        $this->deleted = $deleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deleted
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDeleted()
    {
        return $this->deleted;
    }

    /**
     * Set sold
     *
     * @param \DateTime $sold
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setSold($sold)
    {
        $this->sold = $sold;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sold
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getSold()
    {
        return $this->sold;
    }
}
```

Here is my formType ArticleType :

```
<?php

namespace ArticleBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('category', TextType::class)
            ->add('brand', TextType::class)
            ->add('model', TextType::class)
            ->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'  => array(
                    'Male' => true,
                    'Female' => false,
                )
            ))
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('quantity', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('price', MoneyType::class)
            ->add('imageFile', FileType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ArticleBundle\Entity\Article'
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'articlebundle_article';
    }


}
```

And finally my ArticleController :

```
<?php

namespace ArticleBundle\Controller;

use ArticleBundle\Entity\Article;
use ArticleBundle\Form\Type\ArticleType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/add", name="add")
     */
    public function addArticle(Request $request)
    {
        $article = new Article();

        $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $article->setFosUserId($this->getUser());
            $article->setAdded(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($article);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->render('article/add.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ]);
        }
        return $this->render('article/add.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

My problem is when I flush the entity manager ($em->flush) it records my Article object in my database but without the fosUserId as foreign key that display NULL.

Your advice help me so much.
Thanks

Comment: Just as a tip (to improve readability): Symfonys Base-Controller (which you inherit) has a `getUser()` method. So you can just do `$this->getUser()` in your action(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things you need to change.

First, as @YaatSuka suggested in his/her answer, your `AppBundle\User`-Entity has an error in the `setFosUserId` function:

```
public function setFosUserId($fosUserId)
{
    $this->user = $fosUserId; // Should be: $this->fosUserId = $fosUserId;

    return $this;
}
```

Second: 
In your Controller you're just getting the id of the user while you should be using the entity:

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
```

Should be:

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Or, since you're inheriting the base Symfony controller:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
```

Lastly, although this shouldn't affect the error:
You don't need to add the fosUerId field to the form at all since you're setting it in your controller.

Meaning: You can get rid of the hidden field in your FormType.

Comment: When I try to remove the fosUserId field I get  "This form should not contain extra fields" error. This field became an extra data .. . You know why ?

Comment: How do you render your template?

Comment: Just a simple  `{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}`

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML in your original question? If you removed `fosUserId` from your form type it shouldn't be rendered and should not throw that error. My guess is you didn't refresh your form in the browser when you removed that extra field?

Comment: Yes I well refresh the browser but nothing change.

Comment: Well, the hidden field should no longer get rendered. Optically nothing would change indeed, but that's not the point of that change anyway.

Comment: On the other side I have PURGE the appCache to purge http cache and it seems right.  But this not explains yet why my $fosUserId reference don't pass on my Article table foreign key. You'll have an idea ?

Comment: Did you change the first 2 points I mentioned in the post? Perhaps you could update your original question with your current/updated code.

Comment: The updated code looks fine to me (apart from calling `$article->setFosUserId($this->getUser());` twice in the controller, but that's no big deal.. The 2nd one is just obsolete). Is your schema up-to-date (`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` (or `bin/console` if you're on Symfony 2.8+)? Are you testing this in the `dev` environment or any other? If so: Is the cache cleared? (`php app/console cache:clear --env=[your environment] --no-debug` - again, `bin/console` for Symfony 2.8+)

Comment: Yes ialready tried that, I work in dev environment for the moment with Symfony3.3.9

Comment: I tried unidirectional association instead of bidirectional but it don't change.

Comment: As I said, your code looks fine per se... Did you try dumping the entity and have a look at it? (eg. `echo "<pre>"; \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($article); die();`)

Comment: That's works ! In fact since I change unidirectional by bidirectional association I had stayed with anonymous user but I just tested with connected user and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the problem but it's strange because you should have an error. I'm not sure that you actived errors display.

However, the problem is here, you set a non-existant attribute:

```
public function setFosUserId($fosUserId)
{
    $this->user = $fosUserId; // Wrong attribute

    return $this;
}
```

Instead of:

```
public function setFosUserId($fosUserId)
{
    $this->fosUserId = $fosUserId; // Right attribute

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass the `entity` instead of the `id` (after this correction)?

Comment: Yes  `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {  
            $user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();  

            $article->setFosUserId($user);`